# how to encode unicode characters in python?

Tags: python, unicode

i am trying to encode unicode characters to a specific format that can be encoded and sent to a url using Python 2.

```
input = u"í"

required_output = "%CC%81"

import urllib

print urllib.quote('í') = "%C3%AD"
```

Is there a way to encode as shown so i can get the required output?

Comment: You didn't pass in the same input; your first example is a unicode string, your second, calling `urllib.quote()`, is a *bytestring*.

Comment: What do you mean by control characters? Your example doesn't contain any characters with code points in the range 0-31, which is what we usually call control characters.

Comment: `b'\xCC\x81'` never decodes to `'í'` for any encoding Python has built-in.

Comment: Your expected output and output produced both don't make sense either. What happened to the `i`? CC 81 is the correct UTF-8 sequence for the combining acute accent, but you appear to have forgotten to include the `i`.

Comment: @Blender: it does decode to the [U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT codepoint](https://codepoints.net/U+0301), in UTF-8.

Comment: Last but not least: URLs *normally use NFC normalized, combined characters*, so `i%CC%81` is wrong in that it uses NFD instead. Why do you *have* to have the decomposed form?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import unicodedata, urllib
>>> urllib.quote(unicodedata.normalize("NFD", u"í").encode('utf8'))
'i%CC%81'
```

Comment: though still it has `i` unlike the OPs desired result (+1 as it is the closest result achievable I guess)

Comment: I am going to guess that the OP overlooked the i.

Comment: Note that a URI converted to URL would *always* use NFC, so it's not clear why the OP would want this.

Answer (score 3):

You encoded the [U+00ED LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE](https://codepoints.net/U+00ED), and *not* the separate `i` ASCII letter with the combining acute character that would encode to CC 81, so [U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](https://codepoints.net/U+0301).

If your input data is *combined*, you'd have to decompose it to NFD or NFKD normal forms:

```
normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", input).encode('utf8')
print urllib.quote(normalized)
```

See the [Wikipedia Unicode article section on normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms).

Generally speaking, *for a URL*, you should really stick to the NFC normal form! A [Internationalized Resource Identifier (IRI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier), which allows non-ASCII data, is converted to a URL by using the NFC normal form, so `%C3%AD` is the correct form, not `i%CC%81`.